# CodeIgniter Multiple Upload to 2 different folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am trying to do a multiple file upload where in one `input['file']` is for image and another one is for video

here is the controller

```
public function upload(){
  $data['errorPic'] = $this->validateUpload();  
  $data['errorVid'] = $this->validateUpload2();
}

public function validateUpload(){
    if ( $_FILES AND isset($_FILES['coverImage']['name']) ){
        $config['upload_path'] = 'blogpics/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'png|gif|jpg|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '999999';

        $this->load->library("upload",$config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload("coverImage")){
            return $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
    }   
}

public function validateUpload2(){
    if ( $_FILES AND isset($_FILES['video']['name'])){
        $config['upload_path'] = 'blogvids/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'png|gif|jpg|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '999999';

        $this->load->library("upload",$config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload("video")){
            return $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
    }
}
```

only the first function that is called is working

example:
if I put first the `validateUpload2()` Function on the top of `validateUpload()` function, the first function on the top is working the second one did not

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the reply

I already solved it

I just initialize again the upload using

```
$this->upload->initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is because files uploaded are temporary until moved. Once move_uploaded_file is executed, the temporary file is no longer accessible. If in the second function you call is_uploaded_file, it will return false.

Look into copying the file you wrote to the first directory to the second folder.

**Edit**

Looks like you changed your post around. That scenario is different from the previous.

This time, it looks like there are two separate files being uploaded.

Looks like it should work, but im looking into it. I wonder if it has to do with the reinitialization of the upload helper class.

Comment: so what possible solution can I do? Thanks!